# Discord.js no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

first time posting here. I hope I've posted this correctly.
So, the file exists but its saying it not

(Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.slashCommands/data/1092748438090829837.json')

Asked friend: "Just use a good handler" I tried to look for information in Discord.js guide: "Didnt found" I also tried to find information in this website‍♂️ So, Guys can you help and and give me some tips

I am using discord.js v14 and node.js v18.15.0

Code:

```
const { MessageEmbed, CommandInteractionOptionResolver, ApplicationCommandType, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');
const noblox = require('noblox.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const dataDir = '.slashCommands/data/';

module.exports = {
  name: 'update',
  description: 'Update roles for a user',
  type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  options: [
    {
      name: 'member',
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
      description: 'The member you want to update',
      required: true,
    },
  ],

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const userId = interaction.options.getUser('member').id;
    const guildMember = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(userId);
    const guild = interaction.guild;

    // Add this line to get the guild id
    const guildId = interaction.guild.id;

    // Load the group data and etc
    const groups = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${dataDir}${guildId}.json`, 'utf8'));
```

File structure:
[image: Picture 1]

Error message:
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: "So, the file exists" — What file?

Comment: "but its saying it not" – How so? Is there an error message? If so, quote the complete error message!

Comment: There's rather a lot of code in your question. Can you reduce it to a [mcve]?

Comment: @Quentin Fixed for you

Comment: You got the directory name wrong.

Comment: wdym, i got the directory name wrong. i checked twice

Comment: In the screenshot the directory name starts with an `s`. The director you are telling the code to look for starts with a period.

Comment: Let me try to fix from const dataDir = '.slashCommands/data/'; to const dataDir = 'slashCommands/data/';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wrote

`const dataDir = '.slashCommands/data/';`

the problem is that the directory is wrong
i think you meant by

`const dataDir = './slashCommands/data/';`